# What theorem tells us that we can always find $n$ prime numbers for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: real-analysis, prime-numbers, proof-explanation

Consider the theorem

Let $\{A_1,...,A_n\}$ be a finite collection of sets such that each $A_i$ is countable. Then $A_1\times...\times A_n$ is countable.

I saw the following proof in a book

> It suffices to assume $A_i=\mathbb{N}$ for each $i$, and hence,
> $A=\mathbb{N}^n$. Pick $n$ distinct prime numbers, say $p_1,...,p_n$
> and define $f:\mathbb{N}^n\to\mathbb{N}$ by
> $f(k_1,...,k_n)=p_1^{k_1}\cdot ...\cdot p_n^{k_n}$. It should be clear
> from the fundamental theorem of arithmetic (every natural number has a
> unique factorization into primes) that $f$ is one-to-one. Hence,
> $\mathbb{N}^n$ is countable.

What theorem tells us that we can always find $n$ prime numbers for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$? That is, this theorem seems important, does it have some special name?

Could we also have written the proof as

> Pick $n$ prime numbers $p_1,...,p_n$.
>
> Let $A_i=\{a_{i,1},a_{i,2},...\}$.
>
> Let $A=A_1\times...\times A_n$.
>
> Let $B=\{p_1^{k_1}\cdot... \cdot p_n^{k_n}: k_i\in \mathbb{N}\}$.
>
> Define $f:B\to A$ as
>
> $$f(p_1^{k_1}\cdot ...\cdot p_n^{k_n})=(a_{1,k_1},a_{2,k_2},...,a_{n,k_n})\}$$
>
> Then $f$ is onto and thus $A$ is countable.

Comment: We know that there are infinite many prime numbers becsuae of Euclid. Therefore we can pick up $n$ prime numbers no matter how large $n$ is.

Comment: Cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem)

Comment: For both the original form of the proof and your surjective version, you need to make use of additional results about cardinality, or at least countability, that are not explicitly mentioned. It also depends on exactly how you are defining "countable". Both proof explicitly require the sets to be infinite, but "countable" traditionally also includes finite sets. If you define "countable" as "in bijection with a subset of $\Bbb N$", then your version requires a restriction of the domain to be injective, and the original a restriction of range to be surjective.